# Listpicker not opening

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, listpicker

Okay, I created a listbox the items are bound to it, and for some reason it wont open on tap. But I can see that the first item is in probably so are the rest of them.

Here is the code:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Name="lookingForLstBox" Margin="10,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding DiscoveryCollection}" SelectedIndex="{Binding PickerSelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" LostFocus="lookingForLstBox_LostFocus">
    <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
    <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 21 0 20">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Margin="16 0 0 0" FontSize="43" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
</toolkit:ListPicker>

public IList<Discovery> DiscoveryCollection { get; private set; }

public struct Discovery
{
    public int id { get; set;}
    public string name { get; set;}
}
```

Is this a known bug? because I think I did everything right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, this bug was fixed in the silverlightToolkit Oct11.